# Get-a-Clue™ Crossword

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, lateral-thinking, crosswords

Complete the crossword.

- Each answer is one word.
- (n) is noun and (v) is verb.

[image]

collection
1D. ↑ (n)
1A. ↑ (n)
2D. ↑ (n)
3D. ↑ (n)
4A. ↑ (v)
5A. ↑ (n)
6D. ↑ (v)
7D. ↑ (v)
8A. ↑ (n)
9A. ↑ (v)
10A. ↑ (v)
11D. ↑ (n)

<sub>Note: 9A has 2 possible correct answers, and that is fine.</sub>

---

Text version of the crossword:
█ = blanks where letters are needed

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _ _ _  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _ _ _  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _ █ _ █ _ _ _  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _ R _ █ █ █ █  
_ _ _ _ _ █ █ █ █ █ _ █ _ _ _  
█ _ _ _ _ █ _ █ _ █ _ █ _ █ _  
█ █ S █ █ █ _ █ _ █ █ █ █ █ █  
█ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ S _ █ _  
█ █ █ █ H _ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ █ █  
█ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ █ _
```

Comment: I'm going in all kind of directions here. Just to be sure, no specific knowledge is required other than some trivial?

Comment: Upvote this comment if you have found at least one of the words. This is to help me gauge puzzle difficulty, progress, and whether to add a hint.

Comment: I have upvoted the feedback comment, but I can't really be sure whether I'm allowed to. I have a theory as to how the puzzle works, but the addition of the knowledge tag makes me doubt it. I thought the only knowledge required would be a good English vocabulary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How the Get-a-Clue™ Crossword works:

> Every entry is clued by an up arrow plus an indication whether the answer is a verb or a noun. That means that every word is clued by the answer to the previous clue. The first word is clued by "collection".
>
>  (My first thought was that all answers would be synonyms of direction or upwards or rise and I pencilled in *arrow* for 3 down. Of course, that didn't lead anywhere useful.)

The grid:

> ```
>                           P
>                           R
>                   F   A   O
>                   I   R   G A I N
>               S C E N E   R
>     T         E   L   N   E   D
>     R E S U L T   D   A N S W E R
>     I                     S   V
>     C A T C H               N E T
>     K                         L
>                               O
>                               P
> ```

With the individual answers:

> 1D. ↑ (*n.*)      set
>  1A. ↑ (*n.*)      scene
>  2D. ↑ (*n.*)      arena
>  3D. ↑ (*n.*)      field
>  4A. ↑ (*v.*)      answer
>  5A. ↑ (*n.*)      result
>  6D. ↑ (*v.*)      develop
>  7D. ↑ (*v.*)      progress
>  8A. ↑ (*n.*)      gain
>  9A. ↑ (*v.*)      get / net
> 10A. ↑ (*v.*)      catch
> 11D. ↑ (*n.*)      trick

Remarks:

> The idea of this puzzle is simple, but the puzzle itself is quite hard. Except the first, rather obvious entry, every word ha s already at least one letter filled in from the start or from previous answers. When the next clue after a verb descrines a noun or vice versa, you can narrow down the choices, because the answer must be a word that can be both a verb and a noun. You can also look one or two words ahead, but the puzzle must be solved more or less in the order of the clues, which can lead to some backtracking.
>
>  Once you are on the right path, the answers fall into place, though. Unless I'm missing something, the pizzle lacks confirmation, so that I'm not sure that I have the correct answer.
>
>  Some connexions are not obvious, for example *field* → *answer* ("to field/deal with/answer questions"), but they are backed up by thesauruses. I've used the online thesaurus of [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus), the synonym dictionary of [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms) to find words and [Onlelook](https://onelook.com/) for fiding word patterns. Thanks to JLee, who pointed out a wrong word in a now deleted comment to the question.

Comment: Nailed it! My original intention was to include the entire last word, "trick" so that the solver could also work backwards, but eventually decided that it would make it too easy. At that point, I should have instead included a puzzle-wide clue for the final word, in order to provide some confirmation. Great job!